# driver.findelements to check if element is present or not takes time

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find a link in a page using `findElements`. For evaluating this statement it takes a lot of time . Is there a efficient way to find if the link is present or not?

```
driver.findElements(By.linkText("New pool")).size()<=0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to finding the element by it's text.  I would try finding the element by it's id or by a class name, as this should make it more efficient to find. More info: http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html.

Also you said you were try to find a link.  If you are finding a single link, you just use the `driver.findElement()` method.  If you are using this to make sure the element is on the page, you could look into using a `WebDriverWait` instead. More info: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp.

Lastly you could also look into creating a separate custom method that would use a display check and catch an exception to check if an element is present, like:

```
public boolean isExists(By by) {
  try {
    return driver.findElement(by).isDisplayed();
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `WebDriverWait` will only be useful if you want to wait until element appears (or any other condition is met). It is not helpful if element is already present on the page